# Longest Palindrome Using Recursion in Java

Tags: java, string, recursion, palindrome

I am trying to get the longest palindrome in a string using recursion. Here is my code:

```
public class longestPalindrome{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter a string: ");
        String sentence = "iprefer";            //replace with input.nextLine();

        System.out.println();

        longestPalindrome(sentence, sentence, 1, 1, 0, 0);
    }
//                                                                          1           1                   0               0
    private static void longestPalindrome(String str, String ORIGINAL, int level, int possibilities, int counter, int removedChars) {      
        if (str.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", "").toLowerCase().equals(new StringBuffer(str).reverse().toString().replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", "").toLowerCase()) && str.length() >= 3) {
            System.out.println("The longest palindrome in the string is:" + str);
        }
        else if (str.length() < 3) {
            System.out.println("A palindrome of three characters or more does not exist in the string.");
        }
        else if (possibilities < level) {
            longestPalindrome(str.substring(counter, (ORIGINAL.length() - removedChars) + counter), ORIGINAL, level, ++possibilities, ++counter, removedChars);
        }
        else {
            longestPalindrome(ORIGINAL, ORIGINAL, ++level, 0, 0, ++removedChars);
        }
    }
}
```

So this code does not exactly work and I don't know how to fix it. Here is my explanation:

Say that the input string is: "iprefer".

The way I would check for it would be:

[An image to demonstrate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROSMj.jpg)

The longest palindrome is "refer" in this string.

I will walk through my code:

The sentence is sent to the palindrome function.

```
 if (str.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", "").toLowerCase().equals(new StringBuffer(str).reverse().toString().replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", "").toLowerCase()) && str.length() >= 3) {
     System.out.println("The longest palindrome in the string is:" + str);
 }
```

This if-statement is to check if the string is a palindrome. I don't change the actual string because I want to return the original exactly. I replace all spaces and make it lowercase and I check if it is a palindrome. If not:

```
 else if (str.length() < 3) {
      System.out.println("A palindrome of three characters or more does not exist in the string.");
 }
```

I check if the string (str) is less than 3 characters long. If so, a palindrome does not exist. If it is greater or equal than 3 characters long, I move on the the recursion statement.

```
 else if (possibilities < level) {
      longestPalindrome(str.substring(counter, (ORIGINAL.length() - removedChars) + counter), ORIGINAL, level, ++possibilities, ++counter, removedChars);
 }
```

This is where it gets complicated to explain. Every additional level, the number of possibilities increases by one. For example, at level 1, there is 1 possibility. At level 2, there are two possibilities and so on. Therefore we can conclude that the # of possibilities = level. If the number of possibilities < level, it still need to find more possibilities. So my recursion statement sends a substring but these would be the values according to the sample string: "iprefer". Level 2: 1. str.substring(0,7-1+0) and 2. str.substring(1,7-1+1). And it repeats the process. If the possibilities = level, then:

```
 else {
      longestPalindrome(ORIGINAL, ORIGINAL, ++level, 0, 0, ++removedChars);
 }
```

I reset all the values but I increase the level and the number of removed characters.

I am not sure if that explanation made any sense, but I can clarify if there is an issue. The problem is: the code is not working as intended. I have gone through the code the way I think it would execute and it works in my brain. I have tried using the debugger to figure out the problem, but I can't. I have come to seek some help. I am still learning java so forgive me if there are any stupid mistakes in my code. Thanks for your help!

EDIT: This is the current output of the strings:

```
 iprefer
 iprefer
 iprefe
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out           of range: 7
at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1907)
at recursionq61.RecursionQ61.longestPalindrome(RecursionQ61.java:30)
at recursionq61.RecursionQ61.longestPalindrome(RecursionQ61.java:30)
at recursionq61.RecursionQ61.longestPalindrome(RecursionQ61.java:33)
at recursionq61.RecursionQ61.main(RecursionQ61.java:16)
 Java Result: 1
```

EDIT 2: I am forbidden to use loops.

EDIT 3: Ok, so it seems like I figured it out.

```
public class RecursionQ61 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter a string: ");
        String sentence = "i prefer pi";            //input.nextLine();

        System.out.println();

        longestPalindrome(sentence, sentence, 1, 1, 0, 0);
    }
//                                                                          1           1                   0               0
    private static void longestPalindrome(String str, String ORIGINAL, int level, int possibilities, int counter, int removedChars)   {

        System.out.println(str);

        if (str.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", "").toLowerCase().equals(new StringBuffer(str).reverse().toString().replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", "").toLowerCase()) && str.length() >= 3) {
            System.out.println("The longest palindrome in the string is:" + str);
        }
        else if (str.length() < 3) {
            System.out.println("A palindrome of three characters or more does not exist in the string.");
        }
        else if (possibilities < level) {
            longestPalindrome(ORIGINAL.substring(counter, (ORIGINAL.length() - removedChars) + counter), ORIGINAL, level, ++possibilities, ++counter, removedChars);
        }
        else {
            longestPalindrome(ORIGINAL, ORIGINAL, ++level, 0, 0, ++removedChars);
        }
    }
}
```

I had to change str.substring(counter, (str.length() - removedChars) + counter) to ORIGINAL.substring(counter, (ORIGINAL.length() - removedChars) + counter).

Comment: What's some sample output? What's happening that's not what you want? Explain it some more.

Comment: I'm having trouble following your explanation.  My recommendation: Put a `System.out.println` at the beginning of `longestPalindrome`, to print out the current values of the parameters.  Based on that, you can figure out if the strings it's being called on are what you think they're supposed to be, and then you can figure out whether your whole approach is wrong, or you're doing something else wrong.  My initial attempt shows that it's calling recursively with `"iprefe"` which means you have lost the palindrome.

Comment: Ok, I will edit the question.

Comment: P.S. I assume your instructor told you had to use recursion?  This really isn't a good problem for recursion; this looks like a case where trying to use recursion makes the problem 10x more complicated than a non-recursive approach.  This is a recurring problem in programming classes and I don't know what should be done about it.

Comment: @ajb hmmm... for some reason, the string are very wierd. I am updating the question

Comment: @ajb Yea, my teacher told me to use recursion. I can't use loops either. It would have been very easy with loops

Answer (score 0):

You did not say what the error is. I ran your code and got a StringIndexOutOfBoundsException exception because `(ORIGINAL.length() - removedChars) + counter` was 7 with ORIGINAL="iprefer", counter=removedChars=1. String indices start at 0.

That said, I think your approach is inefficient.  Instead of testing candidate solutions from the longest to the shortest, try going from the shortest to the longest: The shortest palindromes are of length 1 (single character) or 2 (two identical consecutive characters). Given a palindrome P, check if the character before and the character after are the same, and if they are both, say, x, then you found a palindrome P' = xPx.   Continue growing the palindromes and remember the longest you have seen so far.

Comment: hmm... So would I have to do: (ORIGINAL.length() - removedChars) + counter - 1?

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is not an answer because you specifically requested recursive solutions but perhaps this shows how simple and elegant iterative solutions can be.

I will try to put together an elegant recursive one for you but it will probably look a lot like this.

```
private int longestPalindrome(String s, int pos) {
    int delta = 1;
    // Walk outward from the pos - stop when the characters do not match.
    while (pos - delta > 0 && pos + delta < s.length() && s.charAt(pos - delta) == s.charAt(pos + delta)) {
        delta += 1;
    }
    return delta;
}

private String longestPalindrome(String s) {
    int longest = 0;
    int longestLocation = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        // How long is the longest palindrome centered here.
        int length = longestPalindrome(s, i);
        if (length > longest) {
            // Keep track of the longest.
            longest = length;
            longestLocation = i;
        }
    }
    return s.substring(longestLocation - (longest - 1), longestLocation + longest);
}

public void test() {
    System.out.println("Hello");
    String[] tests = new String[]{"iprefer", "madamimadam", "abcdefedcbxqy"};
    for (String test : tests) {
        System.out.println("longestPalindrome(" + test + ")=" + longestPalindrome(test));

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear on what your approach in the above code is, so I'm going to suggest a couple general ways to write programs where you're required to use recursion.

1)  Write the program using loops and get it to work.  Then you can change all your loops to recursive methods, in a pretty mechanical manner, although it's somewhat tedious.  This won't demonstrate an understanding of recursion, but it might be good enough for an assignment, especially when the assignment is one for which recursion isn't appropriate in the first place.

I'll plagiarize some of Old Curmudgeon's code to demonstrate:

```
int delta = 1;
// Walk outward from the pos - stop when the characters do not match.
while (pos - delta > 0 && pos + delta < s.length() && s.charAt(pos - delta) == s.charAt(pos + delta)) {
    delta += 1;
}
return delta;
```

could be turned into a dumb recursive routine like this:

```
int recursiveMethod(int delta, int pos, String s) {
    if (pos - delta > 0 && pos + delta < s.length() && s.charAt(pos - delta) == s.charAt(pos + delta)) {
        return recursiveMethod(delta + 1, pos, s);
    } else {
        return delta;
    }
}
```

I don't really have to know how this works, all I have to do is figure out that it's essentially performing the same steps as the `while` loop.

2)  The essence of recursion is breaking down a problem into smaller parts.  Then you solve your problem by solving the smaller problem(s), and using the solutions to those smaller problems to determine the solution to the larger problem.

The simplest way I can think of for a "longest palindrome" is this: If you have a String `s`, then:

if `s` is itself a palindrome, then it's the longest palindrome in `s`;

otherwise, the longest palindrome must be contained in either `s` with the first character removed, or `s` with the last character removed.  So solve the problem for those two substrings, then pick the longer solution.

(You also need a base case to stop the recursion, but since every string of length 1 automatically satisfies the first test, the base case handles itself trivially.)

This will solve the problem, but very inefficiently.  You will be solving the same subproblems multiple times.  If you start with `s = "abcdefg"`, the recursive method will be called on `"bcdef"` *twice*, via two different paths, and smaller substrings will be solved even more times.  Off the top of my head, I think this is an O(2<sup>n</sup>) or O(n*2<sup>n</sup>) solution, while a simple looping algorithm would be O(n<sup>2</sup>).  But that's what happens when you are forced to use recursion for problems where it's inappropriate.

Comment: I understand, but I still cant figure out why the output strings are so weird.

Comment: @AkshayPathak Are you talking about the output that starts with `Exception`?  That's not an output string, that's a stack trace, and it means that your program threw an exception.  The stack trace says that on line 30 of your program, you tried to use a `substring` and one of the `substring` parameters was out of bounds for the string.

Comment: Yes, I know what you are saying, only the first 3 are the strings, the rest is the error. I wanted to put the stack trace as well in case it helped

Comment: How would you write this using recursion. Would you use another method to do it? I could maybe try that to see if it works. I have to use recursion and cant use loops. The method can change. The method I have is the one my teacher told my about.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code :

```
public class LongestPalinSubstring{
static void printSubStr(String str, int low, int high) {
    System.out.println(str.substring(low, high + 1));
}

static int longestPalSubstr(String str) {
    int maxLength = 1; // The result (length of LPS)

    int start = 0;
    int len = str.length();

    int low, high;

    // One by one consider every character as center
    // point of even and length palindromes
    for (int i = 1; i < len; ++i) 
    {
        // Find the longest even length palindrome with 
        // center points as i-1 and i.
        low = i - 1;
        high = i;
        while (low >= 0 && high < len
                && str.charAt(low) == str.charAt(high)) {
            if (high - low + 1 > maxLength) {
                start = low;
                maxLength = high - low + 1;
            }
            --low;
            ++high;
        }

        // Find the longest odd length palindrome with 
        // center point as i
        low = i - 1;
        high = i + 1;
        while (low >= 0 && high < len
                && str.charAt(low) == str.charAt(high)) {
            if (high - low + 1 > maxLength) {
                start = low;
                maxLength = high - low + 1;
            }
            --low;
            ++high;
        }
    }

    System.out.print("Longest palindrome substring is: ");
    printSubStr(str, start, start + maxLength - 1);

    return maxLength;
}

// Driver program to test above function
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String str = "yourinputstringhere";
    System.out.println("Length is: " + 
                    longestPalSubstr(str));
}
```

}

from http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/longest-palindromic-substring-set-2/